# Chrome for Linux doesn't display pdf's

Tags: linux, google-chrome, pdf, debian, adobe-acrobat

I am using latest chrome package for Debian and it doesn't seem to handle acrobat plugin correctly - when I open a pdf there is just nothing on the screen (kind of dark grey colour). How can I configure it to load acrobat correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Googles own Chrome extension. You can find it at https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn
Having the same problems with pdf and have give this extension a try. Works without glitches and is brutal fast.

Comment: Its works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on Linux. There is a workaround  - when you get the grey screen you can type CTRL-S to download the PDF file.

(from http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=543f0c80bace6c42&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

We can start with the basics:

1. Do you have software to read PDF?
2. Does Chrome know about it?
3. Are you opening a valid PDF?

Comment: Hi (1) yes - acrobat, okular, kpdf, probably others (2) not sure, how do I check? (3) yes

Comment: Here.. Try this: http://rvb.mytanet.de/default-pdf-reader-for-chrome.shtml

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I missed your comment. I get http 403: forbidden

Comment: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=0f007ed4b457df4e&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Does `evince` work? Evince is the default PDF reader that comes with GNOME. `kpdf` or `xpdf` may also apply to your situation.

None of these use a plug-in however--they will all launch in a separate window.

You need to figure out if it's Acrobat, or Chrome that's causing the issue.

Comment: evince works. Acrobat plugin works perfectly with Iceweasel. How can I check what is causing the issue?

Comment: Looks like the issue is with Chrome's handling of its Acrobat plugin, which narrows it down quite nicely. The next question would be "does Chrome have its own plugin, or is it using a Firefox plugin (based off NPAPI?)"

If it's using NPAPI, is Chrome copy of the plugin working (you could copy it from the iceweasel plugins directory...)

If it's its own plugin, that looks like a bug in either Chrome or the plugin. My guess is Chrome.